# How do I create global score counter variable in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, global-variables

I'm new to programming so bear with me here.

I'm trying to create a set of images that do two things when they are tapped by the user:

1. Change the image
2. Add or subtract to their score depending on the image that is tapped

The image change portion works fine. I'm struggling with the add/subtract function.

Both images are created from a struct and need to change the same variable. So if neither image is tapped the score should be zero. If two are tapped the score should be two. If one of them is tapped again the score will go down to 1. It essentially counts the number of images that are currently tapped, and displaying the "x" version of the image.

I have tried to create an ObservableObject and EnvironmentObject using a few different tutorials as guides, and I just can't seem to get them to work.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ScoreCounter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var redCounter: Int = 0
    //var yellowCounter: Int = 0
    //var greenCounter: Int = 0
    //var blueCounter: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
       
    var body: some View {
        
        //MARK - Red Button Stack
        
        HStack {
            
            NumberView(currentImage: "2red", imageName: "2red", xImageName: "2Xred")
            NumberView(currentImage: "3red", imageName: "3red", xImageName: "3Xred")
            
        }
    }
}


struct NumberView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var redScoreCounter: ScoreCounter
    @State var currentImage: String
    @State var imageName: String
    @State var xImageName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.currentImage = self.currentImage == imageName ? xImageName : imageName

            if currentImage == xImageName {
                ScoreCounter.redScoreCounter += 1
            } else {
                ScoreCounter.redScoreCounter -= 1
            }
            print(ScoreCounter.redScoreCounter)
            
        }) {
            Image(currentImage)
        }

    }
}
```

And in SceneDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    var redScoreCounter = ScoreCounter()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to push the `EnvironmentObject` to your subviews inside your `SceneDelegate`. The important part is to call `.environmentObject(redScoreCounter)` on your `ContentView`.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    var redScoreCounter = ScoreCounter()

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()
            .environmentObject(redScoreCounter)

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that fills in a gap. How do I then modify the redScoreCounter variable within the NumberView struct? And will it hold that value if it is modified by another instance of the NumberView struct?

Comment: The EnvironmentObject is injected into your NumberView and there is just one instance of it. (The instance defined inside you SceneDelegate) If you change the value inside of your EnvironmentObject and that value ist publishing (@Published), every View that uses the EnvironmentObject  will be redrawn. Therefore the EnvironmentObject is synced between your views.